# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range while clicking on collectionview item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I created a UICollectionView with Firebase parsed data. If the user clicks on an item he should come to a Detailview. Sometimes it's working fine but sometimes, if I click often fast, I receive the error in the following code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    value = users[indexPath.row] . //Fatal Error index out of range

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoUserDetail", sender: self)
}
```

my numberofitems in sections method:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return users.count
}
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Update your question with your `numberOfItemsInSection` method.

Comment: it seems that the array users changed after you reload the collection which invalidates the currently displayed cells

Comment: I agree with the comment above. If you are changing users but not reloading the collectionview you can get into a state where they are different and have that issue happen.

Comment: yes that was the issue thanks a lot